# Installing Kivy on Windows 7 with Anaconda Python 3.6

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to install Kivy on my Windows 7 PC for Android development using python.

I have followed the steps mentioned here.[kivy installation on Windows](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html)

I am getting the following error for

`python -m pip install kivy`

The first error

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\OEM\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\OEM\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_buffer build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.lib
  buffer.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_buffer' specified multiple times; using first specification
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  cythoning C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics/context.pyx to C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\context.c
  building 'kivy.graphics.context' extension
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\OEM\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\OEM\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\context.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\context.obj
  context.c
  c:\users\oem\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
   error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for kivy
Failed to build kivy
Installing collected packages: kivy
  Running setup.py install for kivy: started
    Running setup.py install for kivy: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\OEM\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\OEM\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-jmayz55y\\kivy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wg_pau0w-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Using distutils

    Detected Cython version 0.25.2
      This version of Cython is untested with Kivy. While this version may
      work perfectly fine, it is possible that you may experience issues. If
      you do have issues, please downgrade to a supported version. It is
      best to use the newest supported version, 0.23, but the minimum
      supported version is 0.20.

      If your platform provides a Cython package, check if you can downgrade
      to a supported version. Otherwise, uninstall the platform package and
      install Cython via pip:

        pip install -I Cython==0.23
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Windows platform detected, force GLEW usage.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
```

The second error:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\OEM\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\OEM\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_buffer build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.lib
    buffer.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_buffer' specified multiple times; using first specification
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.exp
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    skipping 'C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\context.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'kivy.graphics.context' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\OEM\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\OEM\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\context.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\context.obj
    context.c
    c:\users\oem\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jmayz55y\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
     error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
```

What is wrong with the installation?

Answer (score 1):

From your first error message, your cython version may be the culprit. According to the kivy docs:

> This version of Kivy requires at least Cython version 0.23, and has been tested through 0.23. Later versions may work, but as they have not been tested there is no guarantee.

Before installing kivy, try installing the specific cython version 0.23.

```
pip install cython==0.23
```

And then repeat the installation of kivy.

Comment: No it's not. Not here. The more important is the Kivy version.

Answer (score 0):

Py35+ support was added only recently, therefore Kivy 1.9.1 version (that on pypi) won't work on py35+.

To make it work compile either from source:

```
pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/zipball/master
```

or use wheels that are exactly on the same documentation page.